# ASP.NET Bitmap To Image

Tags: asp.net, image, bitmap, bitmapimage

I want to capture image in asp.net. But since there is no picturebox like winform, I have a problem like the one below.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "capture image"? Also, using `System.Drawing` in ASP.NET is not supported: https://photosauce.net/blog/post/5-reasons-you-should-stop-using-systemdrawing-from-aspnet

Comment: Also, it's 2021... why are you using WebForms? It's been obsolete for 13 years now (it stopped being relevant in 2008).

Comment: I suspect you don't yet understand how the web and HTTP work... and why you can't meaningfully usee a DirectMedia stream in server-side code...

Answer (score 0):

But you do have a image control.

So in say we have this markup:

[image]

So two simple buttons. First one just streams the image to the image control.

2nd example uses a handler, and again lets me just set the image using code.

In both cases I did pull the image file from disk - but it could have well been a image stream, or a byte[] array of some image.

I don't think that's your issue or problem. Your problem will be getting a library and client setup with abilities to use the camera.

```
But, yes, you do have a image control
And yes, you can set that image based on bytes[] that represents a image.
```

The code for above is:

```
    protected void cmdStream_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] MyImage;

        MyImage = File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\test3\stopwatch.png");

        Image1.ImageUrl = "Data:Image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(MyImage);
    }

    protected void cmdImageHander_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image1.ImageUrl = "~/ImageHand.ashx";
    }
```

And the code for the custom image handler is this:

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        byte[] MyImage;
        MyImage = File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\test3\stopwatch.png");
        context.Response.ContentType = "Image/png";
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(MyImage);
    }
```

And the results look like this:
(both code bits just shoves the image into the image control on the page.

[image]